# How to monitor create a txt file without using incron?

Tags: monitoring

I know I can use [incron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) or [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to monitor file creation

1- how can I monitor only the creation of .txt files using `incron`?

2- Is there any other ways or scripts I can use to monitor .txt creation without using `incron` or `inotify`?

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative to screwdrivers to turn a screw? Inotify and incron are the tool designed for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incron itself doesn't offer filtering on file names, you can only monitor a directory and all of its files and its subdirectories' files recursively. If you're only interested in some of the files, test the file name in the action.

```
/some/where IN_CREATE /home/user78050/bin/monitor-file-creation $#
```

where `monitor-file-creation` is something like

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  *.txt)
    # do something
    ;;
esac
```